# eBay - are buyer and seller reputation the same?

Tags: ebay

I googled, but can't find a definitive answer.

I have a 1k+ reputation as an eBay buyer.

Now I want to try to get back some of the cash that I have sent by selling.

If I do, will prospective buyers looking at my first sales listing see a reputation of 1k+ or zer0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have a single reputation score. So, your sales listing will show a 1k+ reputation score.

HOWEVER, if someone clicks on your reputation score they can see the full breakdown:

- **Feedback as a seller** (under which it will state "0 Feedback received")
- Feedback as a buyer
- All Feedback
- Feedback left for others

As well as the positive, neutral and negative feedback over the last 1, 6 and 12 months.

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to discover